# How to fix "dotnet build" error with MSB3644 while upgrading winform application to .netcore3.0?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

Dotnet build fails with error MSB3644 for few project like greatermap (gmap). I encountered this while upgrading my winform application from **.NetFramework to .NetCore 3.0**

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1175,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v2.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [C:\Users\xyz\Documents\External\greatmaps\GMap.NET.WindowsForms\GMap.NET.WindowsForms.csproj]
>
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1175,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v2.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [C:\Users\xyz\Documents\External\greatmaps\GMap.NET.Core\GMap.NET.Core.csproj]

Well, I tried to install developer pack as mentioned in the error. But, then realized v2.0 is way too older. How would i fix this error? or how should i upgrade my v2.0 referred projects?

Comment: Well, the error description is pretty clear `The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v2.0 were not found` It looks that you have some references targeting old .NET version and have to update to .NET Core 3 as well

Comment: Well the project mentioned above is this : https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps and yes it is currently in v2.0. I could upgrade it to v3.5 .netframework. Need to check if i downloading https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net35-sp1 would help